# How to check in dash for root

Tags: linux, bash, dash-shell

The standard-solution for bash, see:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/15853/how-can-a-script-check-if-its-being-run-as-root

which is:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 
   exit 1
fi
```

does not work in dash, which is slowly becoming the standard-shell under Linux. How can the above be ported to dash?

Comment: Use `[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]`

Comment: If anything, it's *less* standard with several large distributions switching to `dash` as the system shell. (As far as I know, usage of `bash` as the default *login* shell has remained fairly constant over the last 15-20 years.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `id`:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "I am root!"
fi
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is check for the capabilities I actually require, so that the script will also work correctly for a user who likes to run via an alternate privileged account (*BSD used to have `toor` for superuser with `csh`, which of course nobody in their right mind would want these days, but anyway).

```
test -w /usr/share/bin ||
{ echo "$0: /usr/share/bin not writable -- aborting" >&2; exit 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "id -u" command to get your current effective user id:

```
#!/bin/dash
MYUID=`id -u`
if [ "$MYUID" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "You are root"
else
    echo "You are the non-root user with uid $MYUID"
fi
```